# Sort a typed data set

Tags: c#, sql, linq, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a server-client architecture for a reporting tool,
where the server generates a report and the client displays it.

I have a created a strongly typed data set with one table, and filled it with data rows.
The dataset is always diconnected, because I'm filling it with code that runs with LINQ to Entities. 
The purpose of the dataset is to be displayed in a report,
And I'm using a typed dataset so that the server and client will be in sync about the columns names, types etc...

Now, I want the data in the dataset to be ordered by some columns,
I know how to do this with a dataview, but since there is no strongly typed dataview,
using an untyped dataview would seem to defeat the purpose of using a typed dataset.

I Would appreciate any suggestions on how to address this issue.

Comment: Will [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3917100/706456) help?

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is not the correct way to go, using dataviews is much better, as you will only deal with a single copy of your data.

```
MyDataSet.MyDataRow[] drArray = (MyDataSet.MyDataRow[]) myDataTable.Select(filterString, sortString, DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
MyDataSet.MyDataTable dt = (MyDataSet.MyDataTable) myDataTable.Clone();
if (dr.Length != 0) 
{
    foreach (MyDataSet.MyDataRow dr in drArray) 
    {
        dt.ImportRow(dr);
    }
}
```

Reference from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/da8793cc-5227-4871-a5aa-dfb59c74d8d4/

Comment: Thanks Could you please explain why is the answer proposed in the link wrong? While your answer seems to work , I wold rather sort in LINQ than in free style text.

Comment: When working with datasets, the dataview is just a representation of the dataset's data.  Where with my sample code, we are creating a copy of the dataset, essentially duplicating the object and it's data.  This may seem advantageous with small datasets, but with larger ones, your application may eat up a lot of memory.